# What is the data in brackets called? i.e.: data[i]

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

For example, I have a code. What is [i] on the 3rd line is called and what does data[i] actually do?

```
def binary_search(data, target):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i] == target:
            return True
    return False
```

Script works correctly, saw it in the vid tutorial, but he never explained this part.

Comment: You may want to take a step back and keep reading introductory tutorials. That's a fairly fundamental aspect of containers that any worthwhile tutorial will cover. That accesses the `i`th element in `data` though. It's known typically as "subscripting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I] is used to retrieve the element at the position I in the array

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the index operator.

It is used to index into a sequence (common sequences in Python are `list`, `tuple`, `str`). The index operator can take either a single integer index or a `slice`. Indexes are `0` based, eg the first item is item `0`.

Examples

```
>>> my_array = [7, 9, 13, 42]

>>> my_array[1]  # "Second" item
9

>>> my_array[-1]  # Last item
42

>>> my_array[1:3]  # Slice
[9, 13]
```